# ImportError while importing the wxpython from Spyder

Tags: python, wxpython, spyder, importerror

I am using Spyder 4 and Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.4. I just wrote `import wx` in the console to import the wxpython and got the ImportError. Here is the error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-03faa7660341>", line 1, in <module>
    import wx

  File "/home/divyang/Softwares/Linux/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *

  File "/home/divyang/Softwares/Linux/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *

ImportError: /home/divyang/Softwares/Linux/yes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wx/../../../././libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
```

I tried to google this thing but got no working result. Please help me to solve this.